# How do I solve for $Ex(Y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose a plant has $X$ offspring in a year with $P(X = x) = \frac14$ for $X = 1, 2, 3, 4$ and, independently, each offspring has from one to four offspring in the next year with the same discrete uniform distribution. Let $Y$ denote the total number of offspring in the second generation. Find the values of $Ex(Y)$ and compute $E(Ex(Y))$.

Can any body give some hint for this problem?

Comment: Does *Ex* stand for *expectation* here? If so then what is meant by *E(Ex(Y))*?

Comment: No it does not ^ it stands for the conditional expectation of $Y$ with respect to $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_{n}$ stand for the offspring of the $n$-th generation. Here
$X_{0}=1$ and $X_{1}$ has the distribution that you mention, so
$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}\right)=\frac{5}{2}$ .

Under condition $X_{n-1}=k$ we have an offspring of $\frac{5}{2}k$ in the next generation.
This tells us that $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\mid X_{n-1}\right)=\frac{5}{2}X_{n-1}$
and consequently $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{5}{2}X_{n-1}\right)=\frac{5}{2}\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n-1}\right)$.
This recursion results in $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{n}$.

If you are not that familiar with conditional expectations then notice that:

$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\mid X_{n-1}=k\right)P\left(X_{n-1}=k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{2}kP\left(X_{n-1}=k\right)=\frac{5}{2}\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n-1}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

i take you to mean that each plant continues generating offspring indefinitely. let the probability that the total number of generators after $t$ epochs is $n$ be $p(n,t)$. then if this is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the function $G_t(x)$. we can see that

$$
G_{t+1}(x) = G_t(x)G_t(\frac14[x+x^2+x^3+x^4])
$$
in particular, since $G_0(x) = x^1$ we have 
$$G_1(x)=\frac{x}4[x+x^2+x^3+x^4] = \frac{x^2}4 \frac {x^4-1}{x-1}
$$
and
$$
G_2(x)= \frac{x^2}4 \frac {x^4-1}{x-1}G_1(\frac{x}4 \frac{x^4-1}{x-1})
$$
this expression has terms in $x^j$ for $j=3$ to $25$, which are indeed the minimun and maximum possible numbers of plants after the second generation. for computational purposes let us write:
$$
f(x) =\frac14[x+x^2+x^3+x^4]
$$

and
$$
G_1(x) = xf(x)
$$
then
$$
G_2(x) =G_1(x)G_1(f(x))= xf(x)f(x)f(f(x))=xf(x)^2f(f(x))
$$
using $'$ to denote differentiation wrt $x$:

$$
G_2'(x) = f(x)^2f(f(x)) + 2xf(x)f'(x)f(f(x))+ xf(x)^2f'(x)f'(f(x))
$$
evaluating this expression for $x=1$ we find that the expected number of plants after the second generation is $1 + 2 \times \frac52 + \left(\frac52\right)^2 =$
$$
12.25
$$

Comment: why are you using probability generating function? moreover, this, to me, does not answer the question which is working out the expectation of the 2nd generation. Clearly the question is an exercise using the fact $E[E[Y|X]]=E[Y]$

Comment: i hope i have not misunderstood the question. but if i have not, then you have to find some way of dealing with the recursive element in the situation. a very useful propoerty of generating functions for integer-valued random variables, is that you obtain the expectation by differentiating then setting x to 1. algebraically even the second generation expression is already a bit of a monster, but i am sure there is software available that could ease the tedium of, and reduce the likelihood of error in the computations for the second generation.

Comment: he is asked to work out the conditional expectation of $Y$ wrt to $X$? then the expectation of $Y$.

Comment: have a look at this power-point presentation http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nag48/teaching/MAS3326/3326slides3.pdf